# getopt long and short options

Tags: bash, getopts

Does `getopt` require a short option for every defined long option?  In other words, can I have a long option without being required to define an
equivalent short option.

Comment: `getopt` is outdated since 1986 and does not support long options. Don't use `getopt` for new projects. The right program to use is `getopts` and `getopts` supports long options in the Korn Shell and the Bourne Shell.

Comment: Want to use long options in Bourne Again Shell, but there does not seem to be a posix version, even though I claim that such support should be built-in for all shells.

Comment: Long options have not been standardized by POSIX abd bash does not support long options (even when compiled on a platform like Solaris, where the C library function `getopt(3)` includes support for long options. But the way this C library function supports long options is compatible with what the Korn Shell does, so Korn Shell and Bourne Shell support long options identically. How about asking the `bash` maintainer for omplementing something compatible? See http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html for the documentation on how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does getopt require a short option for every defined long option?

No, it does not.

> can I have a long option without being required to define an equivalent short option.

Yes, you can.